# Enum in c++ with set and get

Tags: c++, enums

I want try calling my set method to get the value in my enum this is my code:

enum.h

```
class OS
{ 
 public:
 enum OSType{WIN,MAC,UNIX,LINUX};
 OStype getOS() const;
 private:
 OSType type;
};
```

enum.cpp

```
auto OS::getOS() const ->OSType
{ return type;
 }


void OS::setOS(OS::OStype t)
{ 
  type = t;
}
```

Now i want to call the method in main

```
 OS test;
 test.setOS();  //what should i write inside this () ?
 test.getOS();  //return the value which was set;
```

I know in the enum that start it with WIN =0, MAC = 1... but i cant just write a number inside or?
And how can i give it out which enum value inside the test?

```
cout<<test<<endl
```

might this work?

Comment: Sorry your question is really confuse! What are you trying to archive?

Comment: I want my object test get the one of the enums (WIN or UNIX.,..) so that when i print out test there a WIN OR UNIX is do you know what i mean?
kay: it is have this in my C++ book but i dont know how to give the object one of the enum

Comment: Take care of capitalization: OSTYPE is not the same thing a OSType. A `(` is not the same thing as `{`.

Comment: None of what you wrote will affect how anything is printed. If you want to change that, you need to override `operator<<`. What is the point of wrapping the `enum` in a class with getters and setters instead of just using the enum itself?

Comment: @Kay oh ups yeah you are right i write it wrong down! thanks for the tip!

Comment: @DanielH yeah my professor want me to write enum in a abstract class then use it for example in another subclass like: 
car class
enum color{RED, blue...}

subclasses BMW , MERCEDES

and use the enum in car, in the subclasses and give it out in main...

Answer (score 2):

An `enum` introduces the names of its members into the enclosing scope.  That means inside `OS` you just use `WIN`, `MAC`, etc. when you want to use them.  That in turn means when you use them outside the class scope that you need to use the scope operator to access them.  So just like accessing any public static member of a class you can get a `enum` value using

```
class_name::enum_member_name
```

or in your case

```
OS::MAC
```

That means you call to `setOS` would look like

```
OS test;
test.setOS(OS::MAC);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!

Can i also print it out that inside test is a MAC?

Comment: @NewUser2810 Like `if(test.getOS() == OS::MAC)`?

Comment: i saw some sites on internet that they use switch cases to check it out what enum members the object have. In my case what inside test is